# How to handle express-session for each subsequent user?

Tags: express, express-session

I am currently working on user authentication and storing JWT tokens in the MongoDB session collection. However, I am encountering an issue with managing multiple sessions. Specifically, I am unable to generate and store sessions for each subsequent user after the first one has successfully logged in.

I am using Thunder Client in VS Code and MongoDB Compass. When I successfully log in with the following credentials:

```
{
  "email": "mile@email.com",
  "password": "asdfAsdf1!"
}
```

a session is successfully created and stored in the session collection, and a connect.sid cookie is generated. However, when I attempt to log in with a different set of credentials:

```
{
  "email": "john@email.com",
  "password": "asdfAsdf2!"
}
```

and the session ID associated with the credentials for mile@email.com is being regenerated into a new ID, instead of creating an entirely new session and not altering the previously generated one.

Please provide suggestions on how to resolve this issue?

This is my code

```
app.use(
  session({
    secret: "key_that_will_sign_the_cookie",
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: false,
    store: MongoStore.create({
      mongoUrl: "mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/addressBook",
      collectionName: "sessions",
    }),
    cookie: {
      secure: false,
      maxAge: 15 * 60 * 1000,
    },
  })
);
```

**userController.ts**

```
export const logIn = asyncHandler(async (req: Request, res: Response) => {
  const { email, password } = req.body;
  const user = await userService.login(email, password);
  const token = tokenService.generateToken(
    user._id,
    "ACCESS_TOKEN_PRIVATE_KEY_HERE"
  );

  // Set session
  (req.session as MySession).jwtToken = token;

  res.status(200).json({
    success: true,
    message: "You have successfully logged in.",
  });
});


export const logout = asyncHandler(async (req: Request, res: Response) => {
  req.session.destroy((err) => {
    if (err) {
      console.log("Error destroying session", err.message);
      res.status(500).json({
        success: false,
        message: "Error logging out.",
      });
    } else {
      res.clearCookie("connect.sid");
      res
        .status(200)
        .json({ success: true, message: "Successfully logged out." });
    }
  });
});
```

**requireAuth.ts (middleware)**

```
const requireAuth = async (req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => {
  try {
    const { jwtToken } = (req.session as MySession) || {};

    if (!jwtToken) {
      return res.status(401).json({ messagE: messages.unauthorized });
    }

    const { sub: userId } = jwt.verify(
      jwtToken,
      "ACCESS_TOKEN_PRIVATE_KEY_HERE"
    );

    const user = await User.findOne({ _id: userId });

    if (!user) {
      return res.status(401).json({ messagE: messages.unauthorized });
    }

    req.user = user;
    next();
  } catch (error: any) {
    return res.status(401).json({ message: error.message });
  }
};
```

***Update***
@jfriend00

The idea behind using session is to organize the code and split the logic into multiple files. Service for business logic but it's probably redundant in my case right now (I will refactor the code later). `jwt` is jsonwebtoken and I am using it to generate authentication token which I am storing in session - [see screenshot](https://prnt.sc/9aiipStoCXZo). Later in `requireAuth` middleware I am verifying validity of that jwt token and using for protecting all contact routes.

```
    router.use(requireAuth);

    router
      .get("/", getAllContacts)
      .get("/favorite", getFavoriteContacts)
      .get("/:contactId", getContactById)
      .post("/", addNewContact)
      .patch("/:contactId", updateContact)
      .delete("/:contactId", deleteContact);
```

**tokenService.ts**

```
import jwt from "jsonwebtoken";
import mongoose from "mongoose";

export const generateToken = (
  userId: mongoose.Types.ObjectId,
  secret: string
): string => {
  const payload = {
    sub: userId,
    iat: Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000),
    exp: Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000) + 15 * 60,
  };

  return jwt.sign(payload, secret);
};

export default { generateToken };
```

**userService.ts**

```
const login = async (email: string, password: string): Promise<IUserDoc> => {
  loginValidation(email, password);

  const user = await getUserByEmail(email);
  const isValidUser = user && (await user.isPasswordMatch(password));

  if (!isValidUser) {
    throw new ApiError(400, messages.incorrectCredentials);
  }

  return user;
};
```

The session captured in the screenshot is the one stored when I log in with one user (for example, email: mile@email.com). Subsequently, when I enter the credentials for a second user and click 'login,' the expiration date of the session stored **for the previous user** is updated and new jwtToken is generated also. Why is this happening? Shouldn't a new session be created independently of the first one? Also I want to mention that cookie `connect.sid` is remaining the same as before, it's not changed.

And yes, instead of having two separate session objects, I still only have one, and after logging in with each subsequent user, only the expiration date is increased and jwtToken is update. (I've also noticed that the timezone of the database is completely wrong, and I need to check this.)

I apologize for any previous confusion.

Comment: Several questions.  1) What library is tokenService?  And what jwt library is it using? 2) Can you show the code for `userService.login(email, password);`? 3) Are any of these incoming requests coming from Javascript Ajax calls with `fetch()` or `XMLHttpRequest`? 4) If you log the session object and the session cookie on every request from one user are you keeping the same session object or same cookie , but just losing the `jwtToken`?  Or are you getting a different session object or cookie for each successive request from the same user?

Comment: The idea here is we're trying to figure out where you're losing the cookie or session, whether it's core session object or somewhere higher level.

Comment: @jfriend00, I have updated my question, please read again. Thanks

Comment: On another topic, you are putting the whole `user` object into your session, but it appears from `user.isPasswordMatch()` that the user object has credentials in it.  I would recommend that you NOT put the user's credentials into the session.  You don't really want credentials to be stored in yet another database.  They should be retrieved from the one place they are stored, used to authenticate and then discarded, not kept around in live objects in memory unnecessarily or stored into a session database.

Comment: What's your recommendation for how to retrieve authenticated user credentials?

Comment: @jfriend00, can you be more precise ?

Comment: Don't put the whole user object into the session.  Create a new object that only contains the things you really need and does not contain the password hash and put that in the session.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion, but in session I have only jwt token right now.

Comment: OK, you're good then.  I don't know why I thought you were putting the whole `user` object in the session.  It looks like you have just the token and that has just the userId.  You're good.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256121/discussion-between-mile-mijatovic-and-jfriend00).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A session object is connected to a session cookie in a particular browser. If you login as one user and then relogin as a different user in the same browser, it will still use the same session object as the session object is generic and is only associated with the session cookie from the browser. It knows nothing at all about a login. You just use the session object to store your logged in user data. Logging in as a new user, will just overwrite the previous user's data in the session.

If you have an explicit "logout" function, you could either clear or delete the prior session, but you can't count on that because users aren't required to do that before logging in as someone else. Probably what you should do is when you login a user, you should first reinitialize the session object to be empty (clear all prior data) so there's no risk of contamination from one user to the next. Note, none of this is an issue between logins from different browsers because they won't ever share the same session object.

> Shouldn't a new session be created independently of the first one? Also I want to mention that cookie connect.sid is remaining the same as before, it's not changed.

A session object from express-session has nothing to do with login.  Your login is a whole different layer on top of the session.  A session object is connected to a `connect.sid` cookie.  If a client presents the same `connect.sid` cookie, then your server will fetch the same session object.  So, as I explained earlier, if you login as userA in browser 1, that fills in userA's login data into the session object that is associated with the cookie in browser 1.  If you then login as a userB in browser 1 before the session cookie expires, it's still got the same `connect.sid` cookie so it will still be using the exact same session object on the server.  Your code, will then put userB's data into that same session object.

Just remember that express-session is working off a cookie in a specific browser and has nothing at all to do with your own login process.  Your login process is just using the underlying session object to store login data.

Comment: Thank you for your response, after which I realized that I don't actually understand how sessions work. Are there cases where we can have multiple different sessions, for example, for two different users? Is this situation applicable when logging in with one user from Chrome and another user from Firefox for example?

Comment: @MileMijatović - Two different browsers would be maintaining two separate cookies and thus would have two separate sessions (just like two users using separate computers).